# How to mock public methods inside controller

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit

i have a controller which is having many actions. Inside the actions, it is calling other methods which is residing in the same class. How can i mock those methods in such a way that it will return what i want.

```
SomeController{

    def action1={

       method1() //i want to mock this method. this is not a service method

       }

    public def method1(){
        //some code here
       }


    def action2={

       method2() // i want to mock this method
     }

    public def method2(){

       //some code here
     }



}// SomeController
```

i want to mock method1() and method2() such a way that it should return something i define.
Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself

```
 controller.metaClass.method1(){

  //define whatever require
  // some codes

 }

 controller.metaClass.method2(){

 // define whatever require
 // some code

 }
```

Above code worked fine

Thanks for your time!!